# Is redis-cli secure enough to use redis-cli to a remote instance

Tags: redis

A Redis beginner here but really enjoying it and using one of the cloud providers for production and a local instance for dev. I see a lot of discussion online about using Redis and connecting via something like:

```
redis-cli -h angelfish.redistogo.com -p 9001 -a 8765xxxxxxxxxx
```

I don't see a lot of discussion about security in regards to remote connections. Is this secure? Should I be running this over a SSH tunnel or is that unnecessary (as http://momolog.info/2011/12/02/connect-to-redis-via-ssh-tunneling/ suggests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redis-cli` (and all other clients for that matter [at least by default]) use Redis' serialization protocol ([RESP](http://redis.io/topics/protocol)) over TCP in plaintext. That means that, security-wise, it is unsafe and could be potentially eavesdropped and/or `MITM`ed. An `SSH` tunnel is certainly a valid option if you're concerned about potential security implications. An alternative approach is to use a secure proxy such as [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) - this [HOWTO](http://redislabs.com/blog/using-stunnel-to-secure-redis) explains how to install and configure it.